# Angular 6 datatable how to leave whitespaces from strings

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple situation I want to display strings like that "st     ri   ng" inside rows in the material data table, but it actually trim that and I have no clue how to preserve that spaces.

stackbltiz demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-v9oksb?file=app/app.component.ts

the first item of dataSource has modified name: "Hy     dro   gen" but in the table, it is displayed as "Hy dro gen"

Thanks

Comment: you mean you want spaces as code has. but only show one space?

Comment: set white-space:pre-wrap for the column

Comment: white-space: pre-wrap works perfect

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in the **pre**- tag to show the spaces.

From your stackblitz the changes:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><pre>{{element.name}}</pre> </mat-cell>
```

Comment: At stackbltiz it works perfect but in my application I have pre tag displayed as grey textarea with scroll

Comment: Does a CSS Framework or your styles define rules for the pre tag? You can check that with the browsers developer tools. just select the pre- tag there. Then you can  override the style in your styles.css

Answer (score 2):

```
Using string.replace(), you can apply ' ' with &nbsp;
srt = srt.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-xnv6ey?file=app%2Fapp.component.html